# Magento 2 : Payment Method Title not showing in Order view in admin

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I made a custom online payment method. All things are going proper, but in order view page in Admin I am Not getting Payment Method Title. We already set the configuration for title and its same like another payment method also in DB we are getting the payment method code in `sales_order_payment` table. Also getting payment method in order grid but not in Order View. Please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

in `[vendor]/[module]/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` make sure you have something like this (label element)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="my_custompayment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title for my custom payment</label>
                <comment>
                    <!-- comment -->
                </comment>
                <!-- fields -->
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
```

Comment: This relates to the configuration page, not the order view page. The question was asking where the text for the order view page is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get Payment title any where:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
echo $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
?>
```

:)

Comment: You should never use the `ObjectManager` directly in your code, always inject dependencies in your constructor. Read more about [dependency injection in the DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html).

Answer (score 0):

The payment method name comes from the payment title.

```php
$paymentTitle = $block->getMethod()->getConfigData('title', $block->getInfo()->getOrder()->getStoreId());
```

You need to check that the payment method title is set in that order store.